# Redirect users to mobile site using cookie to check

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a script in my html code (main page):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
     if (screen.width <= 550) {
     window.location.href = "http://EXAMPLE/chooice.html";
          }
  //-->
  </script>
```

Ok i'ts plain and simple. redirect the user to the chooice.html whenever you are under the 550px area. Cool. Works..

Now here is the problem. I have setup chooice.html to have two buttons (**one of them says go to mobile site, the other one says go to main website**). So my button that says go to main website is were the script is. So if I as a user chooice the regular site my  script will trigger it once again and I will go back to the chooice.html site.... Fail!

I started thinking that I can use a **cookie** for this to check if it needs a redirect or not? You guys get me? I don't know too much javascript so if anyone could help me that would be awesome but I think a cookie is the way to go at this point.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, a cookie, or localstorage can certainly solve this issue.

Comment: I have no clue how to setup a cookie, mate. Help me out :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: if your mobile and main websites haven't different functionality you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Just make other design for pages with width smaller 550px. Ex.: `@media (max-width: 550px) {...`

Comment: it's more then just a couple of style changes...

Comment: then media queries would be the way to go. The one thing media queries can't do though is prevent images stylesheets and js scripts in the html from being downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Javascript cookies.

To write to them, use the following formats

```
document.cookie="item=value";
document.cookie="item=value; expires=Mon, 1 Jan 2014 00:00:00 UTC";
document.cookie="item=value; expires=Mon, 1 Jan 2014 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

You can then read it from the following item

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
```

If you need anymore information, take a look at the following link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp